# CROSS APPLY performance difference

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that takes about 30 seconds to run that returns 1 record.
The function used in the CROSS APPLY is instant when run with the BrandId of this record.

```
SELECT 
   b.BrandId,
   b.Name,
   ah.Type,
   c.ContactEmails,
   c.ContactNumbers,
   c.ContactLinks
FROM 
   @IdsToFilterBy ids
JOIN dbo.AccountHandler ah ON ah.AccountHandlerId = ids.Id
JOIN dbo.Brand b ON ah.RepresentedByBrandId = b.BrandId
CROSS APPLY dbo.[fn_GetBrandContactDetails](b.BrandId) AS c
```

However if I just change the table I get the BrandId from for the the CROSS APPLY..

```
SELECT 
   b.BrandId,
   b.Name,
   ah.Type,
   c.ContactEmails,
   c.ContactNumbers,
   c.ContactLinks
FROM 
   @IdsToFilterBy ids
JOIN dbo.AccountHandler ah ON ah.AccountHandlerId = ids.Id
JOIN dbo.Brand b ON ah.RepresentedByBrandId = b.BrandId
CROSS APPLY dbo.[fn_GetBrandContactDetails](ah.RepresentedByBrandId) AS c <-- change here
```

the query now only takes 2 seconds to run.  As I join `dbo.Brand b ON cah.RepresentedByBrandId = b.BrandId` I would expect them to be the same.

Can someone explain why the huge performance difference?

**UPDATE**

The difference is because the CROSS APPLY is running on the whole Brand table when I use b.BrandId and the whole AccountHandler table when I use ah.RepresentedByBrandId.  The AccountHandler table is considerably smaller.

However I was expecting the CROSS APPLY to run just on the results of the JOINs which is one 1 record.  Is this possible or have I miss understood CROSS APPLY?

Comment: doesn't the different execution plan give any  hint?

Comment: I'm not to good at reading those but it seems it runs the cross apply for the whole Brands table when I use b.BrandId and not just the subset created by the join

Comment: Possible I am blind. But where declared `cah` alias in the second query?

Comment: @Devart - sharp eyes, but don't it `cah` in the first neither

Comment: ok... let's assume that `cah` was meant to be `ah`. Since CROSS APPLY applies the function to every every row. Then the next question would be, how many different rows have each of the tables returns?

Comment: Yep sorry, that was a typo. Fixed.  Looking at the Execution plan it is running the cross apply for the whole table. Not just the rows left after the JOINS. Maybe I have misunderstood how CROSS APPLY works.

Comment: It's not about CROSS APPLY, it's (probably) about different indexing and data structure on two tables.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Found it.

To force the CROSS APPLY to run on the sub set of results from the JOINs and not on the whole table before the JOINS I used OPTION (FORCE ORDER)

```
SELECT 
   b.BrandId,
   b.Name,
   ah.Type,
   c.ContactEmails,
   c.ContactNumbers,
   c.ContactLinks
FROM 
   @IdsToFilterBy ids
JOIN dbo.AccountHandler ah ON ah.AccountHandlerId = ids.Id
JOIN dbo.Brand b ON ah.RepresentedByBrandId = b.BrandId
CROSS APPLY dbo.[fn_GetBrandContactDetails](b.BrandId) AS c
OPTION (FORCE ORDER)
```

This now runs instantly and looking at the execution plan the function is only being called for the one result and not the whole db table.

Comment: FORCE ORDER doesn't always help, I had to use an intermediate table to store the "main query" results then cross apply it with the function.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I solved it using OUTER APPLY instead of CROSS APPLY.