# Speed up Cross Apply query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssrs-2012

I have a query uses Cross Apply. I need to run the query for multiple [Quote Id]s. Here is my original query:

```
SELECT distinct
       [Reports].[Quote_Header_Details_vw].[Quote_Id]    
      ,[Reports].[Quote_Header_Details_vw].[Quote_Created]
      ,[Reports].[Quote_Header_Details_vw].[Com_Product]
      ,[Reports].[Quote_Header_Details_vw].[Ene_Product]
      ,b.[Completed]
      ,b.[Description]
FROM [Reports].[Quote_Header_Details_vw]
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT Top 1
                         Core.Job.[Completed]
                        ,Core.Job.[Description]
FROM Core.Job
WHERE [Quote_Header_Details_vw].[Quote_Created]>=Core.Job.[Completed] 
And Core.Job.[Description] like '%'+[Reports].[Quote_Header_Details_vw].[Ene_Product]
Order by Core.Job.[Completed] DESC) AS b
```

I understand that a lot time is being spent doing the Top 1 operation within the Cross Apply statement. The Query currently takes over 40 seconds to run for a single Quote ID and as the Core.Job table growth, the query will get slower and slower. It is therefore not a feasible solution for me.

Is there a faster and better way of doing this? Thank you very much. Please note that there is no relationship between [Quote_Header_Details_vw] and [Core.Job] tables, i.e. can not join them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CROSS APPLY performance difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567674/cross-apply-performance-difference)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Got it, thanks.

Comment: @Ashraf Abusada  Thanks. Not the same, the two tables are not related to each other at all.

Comment: Did you tune each of the 2 queries? Use Sql Server Profiler to see if you can do that first, if those are optimized (good indexes etc) then look at the `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: Your filter "Core.Job.[Description] like '%'+[Reports].[Quote_Header_Details_vw].[Ene_Product]" is non sargable and will be doing a full table scan for every single record just to return one row.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the filter : WHERE [Quote_Header_Details_vw].[Quote_Created]>=Core.Job.[Completed] 
And Core.Job.[Description] like '%'+[Reports].[Quote_Header_Details_vw].[Ene_Product] is 'non sargable', causes long time. Want to know how solve this in a relatively simple way, if there is any :-)

Comment: Just select those two value into a variables

Comment: The best way to fix this is to fix your data model.  Anytime you need like with a wildcard like that your data model is irretrievably broken and must be fixed. You will always have slow queries and the possibility of inaccurate results if you don't fix it. It would be easier to see if there is a way to help you if you post some of the sample data in the the tables you are talking about and then the expected results. Since you are joining to a view it is possible the whole thing could be improved by improving the view as well.

Comment: @HLGEM I agree. Unfortunately, I am not able to amend data configuration (SQL skill are not good enough to do that even if I can do something to the data) :-P Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just put them in variables and then use the variable in the select

```
declare @dd1 varchar(20);
declare @dd2 varchar(20);
select top (1) @dd1 = [name],  @dd2 = [dispName]
from [table]
order by [name] desc; 
select @dd1, @dd2;
```

OP needed specifics

```
declare @dd1 varchar(20);
declare @dd2 varchar(20);

SELECT Top (1)
       @dd1 = Core.Job.[Completed]
     , @dd2 = Core.Job.[Description]
FROM Core.Job
WHERE [Quote_Header_Details_vw].[Quote_Created] >= Core.Job.[Completed] 
And Core.Job.[Description] like '%'+[Reports].[Quote_Header_Details_vw].[Ene_Product]
Order by Core.Job.[Completed] DESC;


SELECT distinct
       [Reports].[Quote_Header_Details_vw].[Quote_Id]    
      ,[Reports].[Quote_Header_Details_vw].[Quote_Created]
      ,[Reports].[Quote_Header_Details_vw].[Com_Product]
      ,[Reports].[Quote_Header_Details_vw].[Ene_Product]
      ,@dd1 as [Completed]
      ,@dd2 as [Description]
FROM [Reports].[Quote_Header_Details_vw];
```

or try

```
select * from 
(
SELECT r.[Quote_Id]    
      ,r.[Quote_Created]
      ,r.[Com_Product]
      ,r.[Ene_Product]
      ,b.[Completed]
      ,b.[Description] 
      ,row_number() over (partition by r.[Quote_Id] order by b.[Completed] desc) as rn
FROM [Reports].[Quote_Header_Details_vw] r
join Core.Job b
       on r.[Quote_Created] >= b.Job.[Completed] 
      And b.[Description] like '%'+r.[Ene_Product]
) tt
where tt.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I do not understand the logic for this.  Table b is ordered by [Completed] DESC, not ordered by [name] DESC. Do I also need to put [Quote_Created] and [Completed] in variables?

Comment: Put the output from the  CROSS APPLY in variables and eliminate the cross apply.   The is just example syntax for how to assign variables.

Comment: That's not going to give the correct values - they need to be evaluated per row hence the apply.

Comment: @GarethLyons You are correct.  I took "Please note that there is no relationship between [Quote_Header_Details_vw] and [Core.Job] tables" to mean that actually was no relationship.  Thanks for the down vote to reinforce the point.

Comment: Thank you both very much. Apologies if I did not make my point clear enough. For each [Quote_Id] from [Reports].[Quote_Header_Details_vw] table, I wanted to find the top 1 [Description] in table b. To create b, I apply the two filters which use information from each [Quote_Header_Details_vw].[Quote_Id]. That means, for each [Quote_Id] row, the table b will be different. @Paparazzi, I will follow your logic to test. Thank you.