# 20s of PAGEIOLATCH_SH on Azure SQL Database with execution plan of 0.06 subtree cost

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-execution-plan

(Azure support is giving vague answers, so I'm turning to Stack Overflow with hope! :))

### Situation

User complains of timeout errors on a query. I run the **same** query twice (same parameters) from MSMS. First run takes *looong* (23s or sometimes 50s), second, third, etc. runs take <1s. Execution Plans are identical and have a subtree cost of 0.0671..

The difference I do notice is a `WaitStats` section in the first Execution Plan with the following values:

```
WaitCount: 2751
WaitTimeMS: 6
WaitType: MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT

WaitCount: 2751
WaitTimeMS: 6
WaitType: IO_QUEUE_LIMIT

WaitCount: 669
WaitTimeMS: 20360
WaitType: PAGEIOLATCH_SH
```

Azure SQL DTU is averaging around 5% max.

Azure Support says it's probably the Execution Plan compilation time. I doubt that since [clearing the Proc Cache](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tip_of_the_day/2016/06/03/sql-tip-of-the-day-clear-the-proc-cache-in-sql-azure/) does **not** reintroduce the long waits after the first run.

The execution plan "leafs" are `Index Seek (NonClustedred)`, `Key Lookup (Clustered)` and `RID Lookup (Heap)`. The `RID Lookup` being 39% (of the 0.0671). A single row is returned (*i.e.* `TOP 1`).

3 tables are in the query with `CROSS APPLY`. The biggest one has 8 million rows and contains a ~40KB `VARBINARY` column (not referenced nor returned anywhere in the query).

#### Query

```
DECLARE @p0 VARCHAR(50); SET @p0 = '<GUID1>'

SELECT TOP 1 p.Id, p.DateCreatedUtc, p.PreviousOwnerId
FROM (
    -- last project save
    SELECT ps.Id AS psId, p.*
    FROM Projects p
    CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM ProjectSaves
      WHERE ProjectId = p.Id
      ORDER BY LastModifiedUtc DESC
    ) AS ps
    WHERE p.OwnerId = @p0
) p
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM ProjectSavePhotos
    WHERE ProjectSaveId = p.psId AND (name LIKE 'uploads%')
) ps
WHERE P.IsDeleted = 0 AND p.Id NOT IN ('<GUID2>')
ORDER BY p.DateCreatedUtc DESC
```

`p.OwnerId` is indexed and Azure automatically created two more indexes:

1. on `OwnerId` and `Id` and
2. on `IsDeleted`, `OwnerId` and `Id`

`ps.ProjectId` is indexed and includes `LastModifiedUtc`

`psp.ProjectSaveId` is indexed and includes `name`

[image: Execution Plan]

### Question

How can I diagnose the root cause of the 20s `PAGEIOLATCH_SH`? Could it be the mere presence of the `VARBINARY` column? If so, how can I confirm that?

### References read

https://www.sqlshack.com/handling-excessive-sql-server-pageiolatch_sh-wait-types/

https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/io-subsystem/knee-jerk-waits-pageiolatch-sh

Comment: Not sure if you want to do this in production but does running DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS cause the query to be slow, and then once it's cached it's fast?

Comment: The `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` wait corresponds to pages being pulled from disk to the buffer. Once pages have loaded in system memory, they remain there until evicted. This is the reason why the first run of your query takes more time than the subsequent runs.

Comment: @EstienneGranet, what are pages exactly? Index data, row data, chunk of rows?

Comment: questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics) and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps

Comment: Pasting screenshots doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the effect of SQL Azure Database shrinking memory allocation after the database has not been used for some time or the database tier has been scaled. The behavior is exactly as you mention, the first execution or first few executions run with poor performance until memory allocation goes back to normal. You won't see that on a database continuously used.

That behavior on memory allocation creates those waits you are seeing during the first executions of the query, and you don't see that behavior with Microsoft SQL Server. For things like these I commonly say that Azure SQL Database and SQL Server are not the same, they are different in many ways.

Comment: Thanks. What is weird though is that I have automated tests that run every 30 minutes and part of the test flow causes that very query (different parameters) to be ran. I would have assume that would keep everything loaded. Do you have a reference for this memory shrinking?

Comment: No documentation but just run the following: SELECT TOP(5) [type] AS [ClerkType],
SUM(pages_kb) / 1024 AS [SizeMb]
FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY [type]
ORDER BY SUM(pages_kb) DESC

Comment: I reran the query this morning (it took 13s). Before `MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL 1243`, after `MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL 1265`. Does that reinforce your theory?

Comment: Do not run any query on the instance. Wait 5 minutes and run the top 5 again. You should see objects or buffer pool shrinking.

Comment: know of a way to clear all memory allocation so I can reproduce the problem at will on another DB?

Comment: DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS does not exist on Azure SQL Database but scaling up/down the database tier has the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Any type of data is stored as a page in SQL Server. There are different types of page depending on what the page contains (data, index, etc). See [documentation page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> The fundamental unit of data storage in SQL Server is the page. The disk space allocated to a data file (.mdf or .ndf) in a database is logically divided into pages numbered contiguously from 0 to n. Disk I/O operations are performed at the page level. That is, SQL Server reads or writes whole data pages.

When you run a query against your database, the SQL Engine will look in the system memory (buffer) to see if it has all the pages required to execute your query. If some pages are missing, the SQL Engine will load them in memory from the disk.

The `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` wait corresponds to pages being pulled from disk to memory (buffer). Once pages have been loaded in system memory, they remain there until evicted. This is the reason why the first run of your query takes more time than the subsequent runs. During the first run, the SQL Engine needs to retrieve data from disk. For subsequent run, this is no longer the case.

To reduce the first query wait, there are different strategies. As mentioned by Alberto, if you run this query often, then the pages are less likely to be evicted from the buffer. As mentioned by influent, you can rewrite your query or create new indexes so that the SQL Engine does not have to load so many pages. Please post the query plan for further investigation.

Comment: Execution plan added

Comment: Thanks, can you upload a link to a .sqlplan or .xml version of the plan? These have more interesting information.

Comment: [Here's a link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vAHNOlXyoVJY4Fesn0iyjQ7s9_yqj8vJ), I'll take it down after you download it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something this sounds normal, but I'd have to see the execution plan.  You probably want to get rid of that Key Lookup.  Is the Key Lookup grabbing a column that's missing from the index used in the Index Seek?  If yes, add it to the index in the Index Seek and see what happens.  A cross apply with such a large table can eat up a lot of buffer space, depending on how wide it is, but without seeing the query I can't say if there's a better way to get your data.
This might help as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17572392/163072

Adding a clustered PK to ProjectSaves could also make a big difference.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't that appear on the subtree cost though? It's always 0.067. I normally consider this really great. No?

Comment: I added the SQL Query and existing indexes

Comment: I've seen many many cases where the key lookup is supposedly a small part of the plan but as soon as I get rid of it the query is way faster.

Comment: Did you try using OPTION (FORCE ORDER) as is done in the linked page in my answer?

Comment: I'm also wondering if you need the asterisks in your query, or if you can specify the columns instead (if you don't need every column).

Comment: I just tried it, the execution plan only shows minor differences in percentages. `Key Lookup` and `RID Lookup` are still there...

Comment: I'm not sure what you tried. I'm certain you can remove the Key Lookup if you add the missing column to an existing index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159191/discussion-between-dstj-and-influent).