# Azure SQL: Negative SPID = -5

Tags: azure-sql-database

i have AzureSQL database (Provisioned - 2vCore, General Purpose) and sometimes my queries are blocked by session with SPID = -5.

I didnt find anything about this negative SPID and how to avoid blocking my queries.

Thanks for any info and help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Negative Number in SPID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70713486/negative-number-in-spid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions with negative SPID are probably orphaned transactions. You cannot kill the session using KILL command as it needs a positive SPID number. Try running below query on the Azure SQL Database:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(request_owner_guid) as UoW_Guid
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
    WHERE request_session_id =-5
GO
```

This should return a GUID like with the following format:  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Try to kill the session using the GUID instead of the SPID as shown below:

```
KILL '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' -- replace GUID value with UoW_Guid value from above query
```

Comment: executed sp_who2 and your select at the same time, but session_id = -5 doesnt exists when another session is blocked

Comment: screenshot of results [link](https://i.imgur.com/3MBBavI.png)

Comment: Instead of sp_who2 use the queries shown here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/understand-resolve-blocking

Comment: in sys.dm_exec_requests i see, that wait_type on blocked session is "PAGEIOLATCH_SH" and in sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats has blocked session most wait_time_ms on "PAGEIOLATCH_SH"

Comment: Please see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317472/20s-of-pageiolatch-sh-on-azure-sql-database-with-execution-plan-of-0-06-subtree/47320184

Comment: I've noticed this same thing, and I think here's the correct answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70713486/negative-number-in-spid/70714441