# Negative Number in SPID

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am constantly getting Azure SQL Server sessions
with (blocked by) `Blk By` column of `-5`.

What could this session be?

I have searched for negative number SPID
and I can see information for `-2`, `-3`, and `-4`, but not for `-5`.

(I have removed identifiable information for hostname, login dbname columns)

Copied below is a listing from `EXEC sp_who2`

[image: screenshot of EXEC sp_who2]

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for blocking_session_id

> -5 = Session ID of the blocking latch owner could not be determined because it is not tracked for this latch type (for example, for an SH latch).

Edit: I came across [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/negative-blocking-session-ids-5-latch-any-task-releasor/ba-p/3061302) from a Microsoft engineer. The bit I found interesting:

> A​​ blocking session id of -5 alone does not indicate a performance problem. ​​ The addition of -5 is just an indication that the session is waiting on an asynchronous action to complete where-as​​ prior to the addition,​​ the same session wait would have showed​​ blocking session = 0​​ but​​ was still in a wait state.